# Google Apps Script to automatically duplicate a row the number of times a comma appears in a column keeping basic info?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet, google-forms

Can you write a Google Apps Script that can duplicate a row the number of times a comma appears in a column? I have a Google Form that's for scheduling appointments for blower door testing and sometimes there are multiple addresses for one appointment. However, I need each address to be its own entry with the same base info(first name, last name, company name, date requested, etc..)? This is for a Google Form linked to a Google sheet with responses.

1. onSubmit:

Name      Company  Date       Requested Address
John Doe  XYZ      05/30/2022 Lot 1, Lot 2, Lot 3

2. What the script needs to do automatically for all new responses :

Name      Company  Date       Requested Address
John Doe  XYZ      05/30/2022 Lot 1
John Doe  XYZ      05/30/2022 Lot 2
John Doe  XYZ      05/30/2022 Lot 3

3. What I tried: functions/formulas, macro reader, power tools...none of these accomplished automation...I used TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(H:H,",")...recorded a macro (trash), and power tools just wanted money..

Comment: Are you able to include a screenshot of a sample response in your Sheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Try:

```
function onSubmit(e) {

  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e.values))

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
                              .getSheetByName(`onSubmit`)

  const [
    timestamp,
    emailAddress,
    companyName,
    _,
    phoneNumber,
    firstName,
    lastName,
    locations,
    city,
    state,
    zipCode,
    dateRequested,
    ...rest
    ] = e.values

  locations.split(`,`)
           .forEach(i => sheet.appendRow([firstName, lastName, i.trim(), city, state, zipCode, dateRequested]))

}
```

With this, you have some play on how you would like to structure your entries; as of right now, for each location listed in the `H` column, it will add a new row on your specified sheet in the format you've given in your example.

Comment: Does (e) mean event?

Comment: `e` is event object: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events . Additionally, it's worth noting this code will be placed in your Sheets document that stores the responses.

Comment: You did such an awesome job with that! I completely understand the code. I have one or two questions,..Should I replace (e) with (event)? How will this work without referencing the column where the commas are being entered(H:H aka "Inspection site address") I am going to include screen shots now.

Comment: TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(H:H,",") is the formula/function I was developing before I realized Apps Script existed.

Comment: Replacing `e` with `event` won't make a difference, you can replace it with `grapefruit` so long as all references within the function are also `grapefruit`. As for referencing the column, the values are being "destructured" into variables; a handy trick. I will comment the code for you now.

Comment: I primarily just need to know what the order of the answers are to make sure this script will be accurate for you.

Comment: The inspection address street #2-5 will not be used in final version of the Form. Its just a test sheet/enviroment. I was trying stuff lol..

Comment: All good, thank you for sharing these. Can you create a new sheet and paste in an example of how you would like it to look? It will speed things up.

Comment: Done. Can you see it? I updated the second sheet to look like what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I've updated the code to fit your example, add it to your Sheet's code, and set a trigger for the function to run on Form Submit. Then test it by submitting a form! Note: Remember to add the sheet's name in place of `MY_DESTINATION_SHEET_NAME`

Comment: Should this script be ran on the Form or the Sheet?

Comment: Sheet. I requested Editor access so I can get it up and running for you on the test sheet if you would like. It can technically be ran on the Form, but we'll stick to the sheet.

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'values' of undefined (line 3, file "Code")

Comment: @KevinNichols Did this occur after you submitted a form? You can't run this function standalone

Comment: I made a question so you can get credit, lets talk there. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72397388/google-apps-script-typeerror-cannot-read-property-values-of-undefined-line

Comment: I ran it standalone. Moving it to the official form now. The inspection address column is actually "inspection site addresses and/or lot number"...does the name of the headers change how the code ?