# Google Apps Script: TypeError: Cannot read property 'values' of undefined (line 3, file "Code")

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

First, shoutout to NEWAZA for writing this amazing code!

Secondly, please refer to the StackOverflow link/question.

[Google Apps Script to automatically duplicate a row the number of times a comma appears in a column keeping basic info?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72380669/google-apps-script-to-automatically-duplicate-a-row-the-number-of-times-a-comma)

```
 function onSubmit(e) {
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e.values))
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(`onSubmit`)
  const [timestamp,emailAddress,companyName,_,phoneNumber,firstName,lastName,locations,city,state,zipCode,dateRequested,...rest] = e.values;
  locations.split(`,`).forEach(i => sheet.appendRow([firstName, lastName, i.trim(), city, state, zipCode, dateRequested]))
}
```

Finally, I am getting an error in the code. Also, if I wanted to add new columns or questions to the Google form would that be as simple as just add the header's text with the other constants in the script?

Comment: You cannot run the code from the script editor.  It requires the trigger from the onFormSubmit in order to populate the event object

Comment: You can add new columns or questions to the new form with minor modifications to the code.  Provide a specific request and we can assist you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, the error you're receiving indicates there was no `e` or `event object` passed to the function. My guess is you tried to run this function outside of a form response, which is required by design. (The function utilizes values from a form response, no form response - no values).

The best upkeep for this code in regards to adding/deleting questions will be to make sure each constant/variable corresponds to the correct value in the form response.

A handy trick to see each index, question and answer in a form response is to add the following snippet into the top of your `onSubmit()` function:

```
function onSubmit(e) {

  Object.entries(e.namedValues).forEach(([key, value], index) => {
    Logger.log(`[${index}] "${key}" : "${value}"`) 
  })

  // Rest of code goes here.

}
```

**After submitting a response**, you can check the `Execution Logs` and view how your constants/variables should align to.

Essentially, your constants/variables **must** be equal to the response answers.

Hope this helps! If I left anything out, or you need further explanation, just let me know.

Comment: Really quick before I mess everything up...which script editor should I do this to? The one for the SHEET or the FORM? or BOTH?

Comment: I don't recall where the `onSubmit()` function was placed, but whichever editor has it there from last time

Comment: I got it to do its thing. I need your help again though, so look out for another question.